# if $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $A$ is a proper ideal of $R$ ,then $R/A$ is a commutative ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How should I prove that  :
if $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $A$ is a proper ideal of  $R$ ,then show that $R/A$ is a commutative ring with unity?
commutative part will hold because if $R$ is commutative then  $R/A$ has to be commutative

How to show that $R/A$ will have unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1\in R$ then $$ (1+A)(r+ A)=(r+A)(1+A)=r+ A$$

Hence $1+A$ is unity